# Скролл VS fixed и absolute

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Такая проблема , есть кнопки с `position:fixed` и подвал с `position:absolute` , при вызове модального окна , пропадает скролл и все смещается на размер скролла.

Как сделать , что бы смещения не было.

Если JS , то желательно кроссбраузерно и без jquery.

Comment: По-моему scroll и position вещи вообще никак не связанные

Comment: сделайте пример хоть